# Distinguish Pure and Impure functions in Python using Type Hints

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there a way to use type hints to represent pure functions explicitly (i.e. functions that have no side effects)?

Consider the following example, same funcitonality, one without side effects and the other with.

```py
def add_two_pure(numbers: list[float]) -> list[float]:
    return [x + 2 for x in numbers]

numbers = [1.5, 2]
add_two_pure(numbers)
assert numbers == [1.5, 2]


# This is a bad practice, but it is just for illustration
def add_two_impure(numbers: list[float]) -> list[float]:
    for index, value in enumerate(numbers):
        numbers[index] = value + 2
    return numbers

numbers = [1.5, 2]
add_two_impure(numbers)
assert numbers == [3.5, 4]
```

My first guess was to use something like `Final` this but Pylance complains with ""Final" not allowed in this context":

```py
from typing import Final

# Invalid Context
def add_two_pure(numbers: Final[list[float]]) -> list[float]:
    ...
```

Is there any way to make this distinction more explicit? Or is there any PEP already discussing this?

This is a conceptual question, no particular Python version is required.

Comment: If a function runs `print("This is a side effect")` (or sends network traffic, or does anything else other than return an output) it's impure -- how does type hinting detect that?

Comment: Not to mention that `add_two_pure` may be even be a pure function. There's no guarantee that it won't have any side effects for the range of types that its type hints admits. Consider my special `list[float]` subclass performs disk I/O to lazily load values.

Comment: Those are really good points, thank you both Charles and Brian! I think the topic was much more complex than I anticipated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't really have the concept of pure functions.

You can only pass immutable objects to make sure they don't get changed. Such as frozenset, tuple or primitive values.

Alternatively you could write your own decorator to assert that they don't change your variables. e.g.

```py
def purity_check(func):
    def assert_purity(*args, **kwargs):
        hash_or_else = lambda x: hash(x) if isinstance(x, Hashable) else hash(str(x))
        original_ids = list(map(hash_or_else, [*args, *kwargs.values()]))
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        assert all(
            [
                a == b
                for a, b in zip(
                    list(map(hash_or_else, [*args, *kwargs.values()])), original_ids
                )
            ]
        ), f"{func.__name__} is not pure"

    return assert_purity
```

As @Charles Duffy mentioned you can never know if it has other side effects like the `global` keyword, network requests, os-level changes, etc. You'd have to employ static analysis for that.

Comment: Would it be possible to implement something like this but using the typing.Annotated?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like no, not with MyPy anyway. See this issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4468

Comment: Interesting discussion, thanks for sharing